# How can I add additional parameters to highcharts that pulls data from datatables?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, datatables

I am using datatables along with highcharts. When user clicks on buttons 2023, 2022 and ABC button, the charts reload and gives animation effect to the user. It all works fine. However, I have some specific configurations for chart-A (column type). Looks like they are not getting incorporated. For example see below. Why are these configuration not being applied to chart-A?
Link to my code - https://codepen.io/Shawnny-Tandon/pen/bGJeOev

```
var myChart = Highcharts.chart("chart-A", {
            chart: {
                type: "column",
                borderColor: 'lightgray',
                borderWidth: 1,
                marginTop: 50
            },
 tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '{point.key}<br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y:.1f}%</b>'
    },
            legend: {
                symbolRadius: 0,
                itemStyle: {
                    color: '#000000',
                    fontSize: '16px'
                }
            },
            colors: ['#003489', '#ED7D31', '#A5A5A5', '#FFC000', '#5B9BD5'],
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: "Top Seven OCC Award Trends"
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: categories,
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: '600',
                        fontSize: '16px',
                        color: '#000000'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: false,
                tickInterval: 10,
                max: 60,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                    },
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: '600',
                        fontSize: '16px',
                        color: '#000000'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: allSeriesData
        });
```

My complete code -

```js
function initializeDataTable(tableSelector) {
  $(tableSelector).DataTable({
    searching: false,
    responsive: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    ordering: false,
    info: false,
    paging: false,
    initComplete: function(settings, json) {
      let api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);

      var headers = api.columns().header().toArray();
      headers.forEach(function(heading, index) {
        if (index > 0 && index < headers.length) {
          categories.push($(heading).html());
        }
      });

      let rows = api.rows().data().toArray();
      rows.forEach(function(row) {
        group = {
          name: '',
          data: []
        };
        row.forEach(function(cell, idx) {
          if (idx == 0) {
            group.name = cell;
          } else if (idx < row.length) {
            group.data.push(parseFloat(cell.replace(/,/g, '')));
          }
        });
        allSeriesData.push(group);
      });
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (typeof Highcharts !== 'undefined') {
    initializeChart('demo-output', '#example1', 'test 1');
    initializeChart('demo-output2', '#example', 'test 2');

    var allSeriesData = [];
    var categories = [];
    $('#example2').data('scrollX-custom', true);

    if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#example2 table")) {
      initializeDataTable("#example2 table");
    }

    Highcharts.setOptions({
      lang: {
        thousandsSep: ','
      }
    });

    var myChart = Highcharts.chart("chart-A", {
      chart: {
        type: "column",
        borderColor: 'lightgray',
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginTop: 50
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '{point.key}<br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y:.1f}%</b>'
      },
      legend: {
        symbolRadius: 0,
        itemStyle: {
          color: '#000000',
          fontSize: '16px'
        }
      },
      colors: ['#003489', '#ED7D31', '#A5A5A5', '#FFC000', '#5B9BD5'],
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      title: {
        text: "test3"
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: categories,
        labels: {
          style: {
            fontWeight: '600',
            fontSize: '16px',
            color: '#000000'
          }
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: false,
        tickInterval: 10,
        max: 60,
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
          },
          style: {
            fontWeight: '600',
            fontSize: '16px',
            color: '#000000'
          }
        }
      },
      series: allSeriesData
    });

    $('#trend').on('click', function() {
      $('#chart2').hide();
      $('#chart1').hide();
      $('#chart3').show();
      reloadChart('chart-A', '#example2', 'Top Seven test Award Trends', 'chart-A', 'column');
      $('.usa-button').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $('.usa-button').on('click', function() {
      var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
      if (buttonId === 'previous') {
        $('#chart2').show();
        $('#chart1').hide();
        $('#chart3').hide();
        reloadChart('demo-output2', '#example', 'test Awards by NAICS Codes, FY 2022', 'demo-output2', 'pie');
      } else if (buttonId === 'trend') {} else {
        $('#chart2').hide();
        $('#chart1').show();
        $('#chart3').hide();
        reloadChart('demo-output', '#example1', 'test Awards by NAICS Codes, FY 2023', 'demo-output', 'pie');
      }
      $('.usa-button').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $('#current').addClass('active');
  }
});

function initializeChart(chartId, tableId, chartTitle) {
  const table = new DataTable(tableId, {
    searching: false,
    info: true,
    paging: false,
    sort: false
  });

  const chart = Highcharts.chart(chartId, {
    chart: {
      type: 'pie',
      styledMode: false
    },
    title: {
      text: chartTitle
    },
    colors: ['#1a4480', '#e52207', '#e66f0e', '#ffbe2e', '#fee685', '#538200', '#04c585', '#97d4ea', '#009ec1', '#0076d6', '#adadad', '#8168b3', '#d72d79', '#f2938c'],
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '</b> {point.y:.1f}%'
    },
    series: [{
      data: chartData(table)
    }],
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        series: {
          animation: {
            duration: 2000
          }
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
        },
        showInLegend: true
      }
    }
  });

  table.on('draw', function() {
    chart.series[0].setData(chartData(table));
  });

  function chartData(table) {
    var data = [];
    table.rows().every(function() {
      var row = this.data();
      data.push({
        name: row[0],
        y: parseFloat(row[1])
      });
    });

    return data;
  }
}

function reloadChart(chartId, tableId, chartTitle, divId, chartType) {
  //$('#' + divId).DataTable().destroy( true );

  const table = new DataTable(tableId, {
    searching: false,
    info: true,
    paging: false,
    sort: false,
    retrieve: true
  });

  const chart = Highcharts.chart(chartId, {
    chart: {
      type: chartType,
      styledMode: false
    },
    title: {
      text: chartTitle
    },
    colors: ['#1a4480', '#e52207', '#e66f0e', '#ffbe2e', '#fee685', '#538200', '#04c585', '#97d4ea', '#009ec1', '#0076d6', '#adadad', '#8168b3', '#d72d79', '#f2938c'],
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '</b> {point.y:.1f}%'
    },
    series: [{
      data: chartData(table)
    }],
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        series: {
          animation: {
            duration: 2000
          }
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
        },
        showInLegend: true
      }
    }
  });

  table.on('draw', function() {
    chart.series[0].setData(chartData(table), true);
  });

  function chartData(table) {
    var data = [];
    table.rows().every(function() {
      var row = this.data();
      data.push({
        name: row[0],
        y: parseFloat(row[1])
      });
    });

    return data;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/dataTables.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/dataTables.js"></script>

 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

<div class="ar-controls grid-row tablet:flex-justify-start">
<div class="tablet:grid-col-auto margin-bottom-205"><button id="current" class="usa-button usa-button--outline" title="Select to see related information below">2023</button> <button id="previous" class="usa-button usa-button--outline" title="Select to see related information below">2022</button> <button id="trend" class="usa-button usa-button--outline" title="Select to see related information below">ABC</button></div>
</div>

<div id="chart1">
<div id="demo-output" class="chart-display" style=" margin-bottom: 2em; height: 500px; border: solid 1px lightgray;"></div>

<table id="example1" class="display" style=" width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">2023</th>
<th scope="col">Percent</th>
</tr>

</thead>
<tr>
<td scope="row">A</td>
<td>45.9%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">B</td>
<td>22.0%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">C</td>
<td>13.6%</td>
</tr>


</table>
</div>

<div id="chart2" style=" display: none;">
<div id="demo-output2" class="chart-display2" style=" margin-bottom: 2em; height: 680px; border: solid 1px lightgray;"></div>

<table id="example" class="display" style=" width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">2022</th>
<th scope="col">Percent</th>
</tr>

</thead>
<tr>
<td>D</td>
<td>51.90%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>E</td>
<td>18.60%</td>
</tr>


</table>
</div>

    
<div id="chart3" style=" display: none;">
<div id="chart-A" style=" width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

<table class="row-border stripe no-footer cell-border padding-top-5" id="example2" style=" width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr>
<th>Year</th>
<th>column1</th>
<th>column2</th>
<th>column3</th>
<th>column4/th>
<th>column5</th>
<th>column6</th>
<th>column7</th>
</tr>

</thead>
<tr>
<td scope="row" style=" text-align: left; white-space: nowrap;">FY19</td>
<td style=" text-align: left;">42.7%</td>
<td style=" text-align: left;">17.3%</td>
<td style=" text-align: left;">9.5%</td>
<td style=" text-align: left;">3.5%</td>
<td style=" text-align: left;">3.4%</td>
<td style=" text-align: left;">2.9%</td>
<td style=" text-align: left;">2.2%</td>
</tr>


</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use specific chart options depending on the already existing `chartType` parameter. For example:

```
function reloadChart(chartId, tableId, chartTitle, divId, chartType) {
  ...
  const isColumnChart = chartType === 'column';
  const columnOptions = {...};
  const pieOptions = {...};

  const chart = Highcharts.chart(chartId, isColumnChart ? columnOptions : pieOptions);

  ...
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uLbpwnfc/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.chart